# Getting sound to split between computer and external monitor (TV hooked up with HDMI to thunderbolt) from iMac but NOT simulatneously

Tags: macos, imac, audio, hdmi, television

I connected my TV to the iMac last night. When I drag a program up to the TV the sound switches from my computer speakers to my TV speakers; I thought this was a great feature. However, when I wake up the computer the speakers are only working from the iMac. I know how to switch the sound back to the TV and how to play them at the same time, but I just can't get back to that smart audio feature (where the sound comes from the speakers within the display showing the program) that I appreciated so much the first time.

I have scoured the web looking for answers and even called Apple support.

How can I re-enable this feature?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, it may be worth clarifying the version of macOS and model of iMac you're running. It's also good to mention what you've already tried (e.g. while you mention calling Apple, you haven't detailed what you tried as a result of their advice, likewise you mention scouring the web, but not what you've tried). This makes sure we're not suggesting things you've already tried.

Comment: Maybe the first time wasn't "smart audio" but just a lucky coincidence?  Maybe it was just the audio switching to the new target once you plugged in the HDMI, which happened to be the same time you moved the window?

Comment: Ok so the internet has literally just about nothing to say about the topic. A few very small threads about this on PC. Apple care had me reinstall my OS as well as login as a guest user and a few other keyboard commands at startup that I don’t quite remember. I thought it might’ve been a coincidence as well but sure enough it switched back and forth with no problems for like 12 hours.

Comment: Even the folks at Apple couldn’t give me a definitive answer. They just chalked it up to a random fluke, which seems strange to say that an iMac running the latest OS would be producing a feature on accident and not have it available to select